# How to make a footer to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i've succed to do a footer to my fragment but it's not displaying until we saw the end. and i want a fixed footer from the start and not just in the end of the fragment (listView) :

**These is the way i'm doing it :**

```
View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homes, container, false);
View footer = inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_home, null);
listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.homeList);
listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

I know these method is for a listView but i d'on't know how to do it for a fragment.
These is an example of the Facebook Android app : http://www.insidefacebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Screenshot_2014-04-07-13-44-48.png

**PS : see in the bottom of the picture**

**My FooterFragment :**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000"
    tools:context="com.example.user.unchained.FooterHome">


    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="What's New ?"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/status"
    android:id="@+id/watsN"
    android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" | "
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="145dip"
        android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Check In"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="165dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/checkin"
        android:id="@+id/checkIn"
        android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" | "
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="265dip"
        android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" Picture"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="290dip"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/camera"
        android:id="@+id/postPic"
        android:textColor="@color/connexion_button"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you want something like in the picture?

Comment: that's not part of the ListView. In the picture the footer overlaps the List on the bottom

Comment: Ok, but how can i do it please ?

Comment: That's trivial. Let's make the assumption that you have a ListFragment that hosts the `ListView`. You have a transaction that replace the content of a container with the `ListFragment`, in your activity. So, the question is how should I make the container and the footer overlap in my actvity ?

Comment: just add a view containing the footer and align it to the bottom o your layout of the fragment

Comment: to correct your answer i have a Fragment that host the listView and i want just like you say that the footer overlap the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the footer in front of the list view  with `alignParentBottom` set to true, and don't forget to add some paddingBottom to your listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@null"
    >

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/my_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:clipToPadding="false" 
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/footer_height"/> <!-- Set the padding -->


  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_footer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/footer_height"
      android:text="@string/btn_footer_string"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/> <!-- Set to align bottom -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have the footer in a layout ? how can i added it with the listView

Comment: you just need to inflate this layout and set it as the view for your activity/fragment. eg. using `setContentView` or `onCreateView`